# Windows 7 suddenly cannot create any network adapters anymore

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter

A Windows 7 machine, which has been working for years, suddenly cannot connect to networks. It always says **"there is no network adapter"**.

I thought that the RJ45 adapter may be broken, but I tried a USB WIFI and a USB RJ45 Adapter (and successfully installed the drivers), but this doesn't work either. 
It always says "there is no Network adapter".

Any idea what could have happened? Any idea what I could do?

The cable and the network switch work for sure. (I successfully connected a test machine with the same cable, the same IP, on the same switch port.)

There were no changes made to configuration, except for windows updates. Maybe a windows update is the culprit?

Comment: Open Device Manager and find each network adapter. Right click on each one and update the driver. Do for each, restart and test.

Comment: See this also....https://www.askvg.com/fix-network-connections-folder-is-empty-in-windows-not-showing-network-adapters-list/